# Open PDF File with form textbox on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I need to open a pdf file with form texbox included on a form. I use this code to open the pdf file.

```
           `StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text);

            Stream stream = streamReader.BaseStream;

            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] sendbyteArray =binaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(binaryReader.BaseStream.Length));
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
                Response.BinaryWrite(sendbyteArray);
                Response.End();`
```

which is working. I need to add a textbox above the pdf once the pdf file showed. is this possible? please advice. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge this is not possible but if you share what is the purpose of that textbox we can think of another solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply, well I need to display the pdf with file description on it. It can be a textbox or a label.

Comment: ok. So you should be adding the description on time of creating PDF be it converting also. Whenever you are converting it to pdf just add header in source file.